# Energy consumption raspberry pi 2B

Tags: pi-2, power

I would like to calculate the energy consumption of a given process in a Raspberry Pi 2B Rev.1.1 BCM2836. It is fed using the microusb port through a laptop docker via USB.

I'm using atop to get the CPU usage of this proces "java" it shows a constant 110% of CPU, the java process takes 5ms average to perform a given task. Here (https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/power-consumption), we can check a benchmark for different model. In my case, it says 400 mA using all 4 CPUs, however, in idle is 220, so, does make sense to do the following:
In idle state is 220 (by meaning 0% CPU) and 400 mA (400% CPU) so, in approximation and assuming the CPU is lineal we can assume 400-220=180 mA so 110%CPU is 220mA+((180mA/400)*110). In terms of W 1.1W+((1W/400)*110)=1.1W+0.275W=1375mW then the energy consumption of this task is about 6.875 mWs.

This image shows the atop software when running the java task

[image]

Here without the task

[image]

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No you leave out any thinking of the voltage applied when it runs harder. With it being a logarithmic function if the voltage doubled it quadruples the power drawn. Only way to tell for certain is with something like a kill-a-watt meter it will give good enough reading for your purpose.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt

Comment: Isn't it possible to approximate it in formula?